# Actioncable standalone server with ruby on rails broadcasts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, actioncable

Is it possible to have a standalone actioncable server, instead of the server being mounted inside the app, while also having broadcasts come from Ruby on Rails code?

We have had actioncable mounted in the app and everything works fine. However due to some work constraints we are being told to use a standalone server.

Inside a Ruby component class, we use a broadcast as such:

`ActionCable.server.broadcast "update_round_leader_tenant_#{user.tenant_uuid}", broadcast_data`

This is caught in the retrieve method of our channel.

```
class UpdateRoundLeaderChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel

  # subscribed is called when the websocket connection authorization is completed
  # allows the specified channel to be broadcast, and trigger the receive method
  def subscribed
    stream_from "update_round_leader_tenant_#{current_user[:tenant_id]}"
  end

  # This is called by the broadcast elsewhere
  # Rebroadcasts data
  # param: round_data - a hash containing
  #                             an integer, roundId
  #                             an integer, leaderId
  #                             String - leaderName
  def receive(round_data)
    ActionCable.server.broadcast 'UpdateRoundLeaderChannel', message: round_data
  end
end
```

From there, the broadcast in the receive method broadcasts the data to the client. The client (separate React project) only receives the broadcasted data, it does not send any data back to the server.

What I am finding with a standalone server is the initial broadcast does not reach the receive method. I cannot find anything on google trying to do what we're doing. Is it possible? If so what do I need to do to change our app?